# Attaching 'onclick' event to D3 chart background

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I have a D3 histogram chart, onto which I have attached an 'onclick' event to the bars:

```
...
var bar = svg.selectAll(".bar")
        .data(data)
        .enter().append("g")
        .attr("class", "bar")
        .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x(d.x) + "," + y(d.y) + ")"; })
        .on('mouseover', tip.show)
        .on('mouseout', tip.hide)
        .on('click', function(d,i){ //do stuff  });
...
```

This works exactly as expected.  I would also like to attach an 'onclick' event to the background of the chart (ie. everywhere in the chart that is not a bar), but I am having trouble with this.  I have tried attaching the event in a couple ways, but in every case, this new event seems to override my bar-click:

Some attempts:

```
$("svg:not('.bar')").on("click", function(){ //do stuff });

$("g:not('.bar')").on("click", function(){ //do stuff });

var svg = d3.select("#histogram_block").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
        .on("click", function(d,i){
            if (d) { //do stuff}
            else { //do stuff }
        };
```

I am assuming there is a way to add the event handler to the SVG object when it is initialized, but I don't know the correct way to go about this.

Comment: Just a reminder. `$("svg:not('.bar')")` means get the all `svg`s that dont have the `bar` class. It doesnt mean get the `svg`s section outside of the elements with `bar` class.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

The event isn't actually overridden, but both are triggered -- the `onclick` handler for the SVG and for the bar. To prevent this, use the `.stopPropagation()` method (see [the documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#d3_event)). The code looks like this:

```
rect.on("click", function() {
  console.log("rect");
  d3.event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Complete example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/V7mC4/). Compare with the behaviour with stopping the propagation of the event [here](http://jsfiddle.net/V7mC4/1/).

Comment: Great example, thanks.  You should add it to the answer since it's so short.  So what determines the order of events when I click?  The assumption here seems to be that the rectangle's click event fires first, but will that always be the case?

Comment: Events "bubble up" the DOM. The `rect` is a child of the `svg`, so it propagates the event to the `svg`. This is why `.stopPropagation()` works. So yes, the `rect`s click handler should always fire first.

Comment: Thanks, but what would happen if there were overlapping chart elements, both children of the SVG?  Which would fire their click event first?

Comment: You can only click on one element -- the one that's in front at the mouse position. This event bubbles up to parents, siblings are not affected.

Comment: I applied this solution to my problem which is similar to this. But the svg event fires only sometimes. The bar onclick event works fine everytime but the background on-click event fires only some times in random frequency. Any idea why would it behave so ?

Answer (score 1):

In this example (line 246: http://tributary.io/inlet/8361294) I append a new rect with width & height equal to the total chart area, then attach my mouse (or click) events.

```
svg.append("rect")
        .attr({"class": "overlay" , "width": width , "height": height})
        .on({
          "mouseover": function() { /* do stuff */ },
          "mouseout":  function() { /* do stuff */ }, 
          "click":  function() { /* do stuff */ }, 
        });
```

Comment: This does not seem to answer the question, since this doesn't click on a chart's background vs. foreground element.