# d3 Click elements on graph to edit it

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am building a tree graph system in which a user builds a small tree graph on a page.  I am looking for a way to allow a user to click an element in the graph, populate information below and allow them to edit it.

This is the style of graph I am using in D3 v4
https://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/76d6fa0dff4af77544da9dd69aef9249

Is there a way to have click events in D3?

Comment: How exactly does one accomplish this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22941796/attaching-onclick-event-to-d3-chart-background